# trigger error - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger, date

This trigger is meant to raise an exception when I try and insert a record with a dob being more than today's date and insert a record that has dob less than today's date.

I've done this:

```
/* This checks that the dob is before today's date and throws an exception if not */

CREATE FUNCTION check_dateofbirth() RETURNS trigger AS $check_dateofbirth$
DECLARE dob date;
BEGIN
    SELECT passenger.dob INTO dob
    FROM passenger
    WHERE passengerid = passengerid;

    IF dob > now() THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date of birth must be earlier than today';

    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$check_dateofbirth$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
/* this is used to run the function above */
CREATE TRIGGER insert_dateofbirth
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON passenger
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_dateofbirth();
```

When I insert data with dob '2018-09-09', I get the exception 'Date of birth must be earlier than today' which is correct and what I want. However, when I insert data with dob as '1996-09-15', I also get the exception which is wrong because it should insert as the dob is earlier than today. Is the error to do with the format of my dob? Should it be dd/mm/yyyy instead of yyyy/mm/dd??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_dateofbirth() RETURNS trigger AS $check_dateofbirth$
DECLARE dob date;
BEGIN
    IF NEW.dob > now() THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date of birth must be earlier than today';

    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$check_dateofbirth$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You don't need to query the table - just check the NEW record.

Also: `WHERE passengerid = passengerid` will return all rows as it is always true